# With html track elements is the metadata value for the kind attribute used as data via the cue id's?

Tags: html, html5-video, media

I am reading about the track element [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/track)
The track element is used with the video element to display captions, subtitles and other text information.
However, I am confused about one thing.

The article says the *kind* attribute has a ' metadata' value and it explains it as follows.

> metadata
>   Tracks used by scripts. Not visible to the user.

I'm curious how this is used. I am specifically looking for an example. How exactly are tracks 'used by scripts'?
I am guessing that webvtt file cue id's can be used to launch events via JavaScript but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A working example of using metadata can be seen here: http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/demos/mediaelement/track-demo.html

The carousel and the info panel are build from the following metadata webvtt: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/demos/demos/mediaelement/assets/treeOfLife-metadata-en.vtt.

The sourcecode can be found here: https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/demos/demos/mediaelement/assets/track.js

1. To access a textTrack object you can use the textTracks property of the mediaelement or the [track property of the track element](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/demos/demos/mediaelement/assets/track.js#L128).
2. You can listen to events like [cuechange](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/demos/demos/mediaelement/assets/track.js#L128) to get the [activeCues](https://github.com/aFarkas/webshim/blob/gh-pages/demos/demos/mediaelement/assets/track.js#L128) and of course you can check for a specific id of this/those activeCues to react.

In case you want to fully use JS, you don't even have to use webvtt files, you can simply add tracks via the JS API (addTextTrack).